# split column into multi dynamically in python or sql

Tags: python, sql, t-sql, dynamic, data-preprocessing

I'm trying to Split the details column into multi using T-sql or python.

*the table is like this:*

| ID | Details |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | Hotel:Campsite;Message:Reservation inquiries |
| 150 | Page:45-discount-y;PageLink:[https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/|](https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/%7C) |
| 13 | NULL |

There are a lot of keys or columns under the details. So I want a dynamic way to split the details into multiple columns using python or tsql

*The desired output:*

| ID | Details | Hotel | Message | Page | PageLink |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Hotel:Campsite;Message:Reservation inquiries | Campsite | Reservation inquiries | NULL | NULL |
| 150 | Page:45-discount-y;PageLink:https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y | NULL | NULL | 45-discount-y | [https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/|](https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/%7C) |
| 13 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: why not use correct json or xml so that you can use the functions provided

Comment: I suppose a bit of character replacement could, at least, turn that into valid JSON, @nbk (thought the :` in `http://` poses a (small) problem); but getting the data stored in a normalised format to start with would be the ideal in my opinion

Comment: Why is `https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/|` put in `page`, when it's prefixed by `PageLink`, and why is the value not `https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/| NULL`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu My mistake I modify it

Answer (score 0):

First :split part of Data ';' with string_split

second :after split second part of Data with string_split and replace

we use replace for Handle character : in 'Page Link in'

Finally use pivot

```
dECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@scols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)



 set @query = '
 
 
;with cte as (
                    select Id,Details,valuesd,[1],replace( [2],''https//'',''https://'') as [2]   from (
                    select * from (

                                    
                                        select Id,Details,value as valuesd
                                        from  T
                                        cross apply(  
                                                    select *
                                                    from string_split(Details,'';'')
                                        )d

                                    

                    )t 
                    cross apply (

                                select RowN=Row_Number() over (Order by (SELECT NULL)), value 
                                from string_split(replace( t.valuesd,''https://'',''https//''), '':'') 

                    ) d

                    ) src
                    pivot (max(value) for src.RowN in([1],[2])) p
 )

 SELECT   T.id,T.Details,Max([Hotel]) as [Hotel],Max([Message]) as Message,Max([Page]) as Page,Max([PageLink]) as PageLink  from 
             (
                   select Id,Details,  valuesd,[1],[2]
                   from  cte
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
               max( [2])  for [1] in ([Hotel],[Message],[Page],[PageLink])
            ) p 
            right join T on p.id=T.id
            group by T.id,T.Details
            '

execute(@query)
```

You can to insert the basic data with the following codes

```
create table T(id int,Details nvarchar(max))
insert into T
select 15,'Hotel:Campsite;Message:Reservation inquiries' union all
select 150,'Page:45-discount-y;PageLink:https://xx.xx.net/SS/45-discount-y/|' union all
select 13, null
```